# Using Criteria for sub-queries

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

I have two tables in my Database, Tuser and TCompany,
    where

```
Tuser : id | name | email  
Tcompany : id | companyName | userId
```

where userId is foregn key of Tuser table.

I have written a query to get all users whose name start with a

```
Criteria criteria = ctx.getSession().createCriteria(Tuser.class);  
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("name", "a%"));  
List res = criteria.list()
```

Now i need to get all users who do not belong to a company.
    In sql, we can use sub-queries, but i am getting stuck as to how it is done using criteria?

Comment: This question might address it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602490/hibernate-criteria-perform-join-in-subquery-detachedcriteria?rq=1

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Subqueries.html is a factory of subqueries. Each subquery is a criterion that can be added like any other criterion to your criteria.